# How to change image when a button is clicked on Expo?

Tags: reactjs, expo

I am trying to make an app that shows cat pictures on **Expo**. I have a cat picture that is displayed originally. I have a button and when I click the button, I want to change the cat picture that is displayed. Here is what I have:

```
let imageUri = {uri:  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615789591457-74a63395c990?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZG9tZXN0aWMlMjBjYXR8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80'};
```

I define a function that changes the `imageUri` value:

```
const displayImage = async () => {
  imageUri = {uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529778873920-4da4926a72c2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Y3V0ZSUyMGNhdHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80'}
}
```

Then inside of `return()` I do the following:

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('./assets/images/background.png')}
        style={styles.image}
        />
        <Text style={styles.text}> Here is a cat picture </Text>
        <Button
          style = {styles.button}
          title="Display"
          onPress = {() => displayImage()}
        />
        <Image source={imageUri} style = {{width: 155, height: 259}} />
    </View>
```

However, it does not update the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your image is not changing is becuase the state of the component is not changing.  To solve this you need to manage the state of the component data.  You can do this with the hook useState.

Make sure to import useState hook.

```
import {useState} from 'react';
```

Then you can set a state managed variable for your image.

```
const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState( 
     'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615789591457-74a63395c990?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZG9tZXN0aWMlMjBjYXR8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80'
);
```

Then all you need is to update your button press event to call the state hook to set the new image into state.  So when the image changes your components state updates with the new image.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <ImageBackground
    source={require('./assets/images/background.png')}
    style={styles.image}
    />
    <Text style={styles.text}> Here is a cat picture </Text>
    <Button
      style = {styles.button}
      title="Display"
      onPress = {() => setImageUri('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529778873920-4da4926a72c2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Y3V0ZSUyMGNhdHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80')}
    />
    <Image source={imageUri} style = {{width: 155, height: 259}} />
</View>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, `source={imageUri}` needs to be replaced with `source={{uri: imageUri}}` for it to work properly.